# How to return the result of a websql function

Tags: javascript, web-sql

I am using the [websql database](http://ww.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/) in my webapplication to store some data from actual db and fetch it through websql api.

Currently the call is asynchronous, i.e, the result is updated after all the tasks are finished.
I want to change it to synchronous i.e, step by step executed.  Here is the function i am calling from js code

```
  function fetch(model, id, success, error) {
    var tableName = model.prototype.tableName,
        sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + tableName + ' WHERE ' + tableName + '_id = ?';

    if (db) {
      // websql
      db.readTransaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql(sql, [id], function (tr, result) {
          if (result.rows.length === 0) {
            return null;
          } else {
            success(transform(model, result.rows.item(0)));
          }
        }, error);
      });
    } else {
      // localStorage
      throw 'Not implemented';
    }
  }
```

am calling this from a line of code.

```
OB.Dal.fetch(OB.Model.BusinessPartner, businessPartnerId);
```

How can i return the result of the method fetch() and assign it to some variable in the next step. some thing like

```
var bpartner = OB.Dal.fetch(OB.Model.BusinessPartner, businessPartnerId);
model.set('bp', bpartner);
```

--

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't. It's an asynchronous call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web SQL transaction returns empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780911/web-sql-transaction-returns-empty)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there a way to write a custom synchronous call ?

Comment: I don't recall any options for making synchronous WebSQL calls … but that sort of operation would result in highly undesirable locks on the UI anyway.